# How to input CSV file with tinestamp etc. into mahout to achieve similarity function etc.?

Tags: javascript, java, hadoop, machine-learning

Currently, I am trying to input my data to try machine learning purpose, the data is like following with three columns (first one is time, the second one is code and the third one is number):

```
2016-06-05 00:00:00      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:ca4b   0

2016-06-05 00:00:00      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:f2be   0.12549

2016-06-05 00:00:00      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:c8a1   0.14091

2016-06-05 00:00:01      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:ca4b   0

2016-06-05 00:00:01      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:f2be   0.25098

2016-06-05 00:00:01      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:c8a1   0

2016-06-05 00:00:02      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:ca4b   0

2016-06-05 00:00:02      fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:35:f2be   0.25098
```

The following is the code to import the data into mahout:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;
import     org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.NearestNUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.Recommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.RecommendedItem;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;
/**
 */
    public class RecommenderIntro {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // TODO code application logic here
            DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("/home/leo/csv_dump11.csv"));
            UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity (model);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood (2, similarity, model);
            Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender (model, neighborhood, similarity);
            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(1, 1);
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                System.out.println(recommendation);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve the classification function etc.? Please let me know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file is in the wrong format for `FileDataModel`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mr/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/file/FileDataModel.java) you'll see its expecting:

`userID,itemID,timestamp`

Which is in-line with the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error your seeing. Its expecting a `userID` as a `long` and you have a formatted date.

Also note the `timestamp` should be a `long`. The documentation in the source indicates you can provide your own function to parse the date if you override `readTimestampFromString(String)` if you don't want to convert all your dates to milliseconds.

So you'll either need to reformat your data to work with this class or extend it and override the relevant methods need to parse it correctly (if possible).

Comment: Thank you very much, because I am new to JAVA, I do not think I can reformat the data. If possible, could you please show me how to extend it and override it?

Comment: You can use anything to reformat it, python, excel if its small, bash etc. I assume the data set isnt too large, the docs do say `FileDataModel` shouldnt be used for anything too large.

Comment: But I want to keep as it is, because it is time data with current from sensor, if you don't mind could you please show me how to extend it to make it valid to import the original data?

Comment: You should have a go yourself and if you have a problem you can ask another question.